# Loading namespaced modules in Minitest test files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Rails 5.2.1 with minitest 5.1

I have a file `app/strategies/foo/bar/baz.rb` that I want to namespace

baz.rb:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
```

in rails console I can successfully run:
`test = Foo::Bar::Baz.new`

in testing `/test/strategies/foor/bar/baz_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'
class BazTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

test 'I can call it' do
  test = Foo::Bar::Baz.new
end
```

and I get: 
`NameError: uninitialized constant BazTest::Foo`

I've tried varies forms of require at the top of `baz_test.rb`

```
require '/app/strategies/foo/bar/baz'
require '../../../../app/strategies/foo/bar/baz'
require 'baz'
```

All with the same error `*** LoadError Exception: cannot load such file`

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `uninitialized constant Foo`
 also tried just `::Baz.new` and got `uninitialized constant Baz`

Comment: Sometimes the autoloader does not pickup new directories in `app` which can be often be fixed by running `$ spring stop` - you can see if this is the issue by moving the file to the models dir. You can also try `require Rails.root.join('app','strategies','foo','bar','baz')` which gives you an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

`/test/strategies/foo/bar/baz_test.rb` class definition needed to be:

```
class Foo::Bar::BazTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```